# How to change dynamically size of hX tag if the parent div contains a child div of class X

Tags: jquery, dynamic, children

I'm having some problems with jquery and I really hope someone out there can help!

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="widgetContent">
        <div class="thumbNail"> </div>
        <h4>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce feugiat mauris non
            libero.
        </h4>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
        <span class="newsDate">10th March 2011</span>
        <p class="widgetTexSummary">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce feugiat ...</p>
</div>

<div class="widgetContent">
        <div class="widgetEventsDate">
            <span class="month">Mar</span> <span class="date">24</span></div>
        <h4>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce feugiat mauris non
            libero.
        </h4>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
        <span class="newsDate">10th March 2011</span>
        <p class="widgetTexSummary">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce feugiat ...</p>
</div>
```

and the following jquery:

```
 if ($(".widgetContent:has(.thumbNail)")){
         $('h4').css('width', '100px');
     }
     else{$('h4').css('width','195px');}
```

The idea is when I have a child with class 'thumbNail' in a widget  the h4 within the widget would have its size dynamically change to 100px. In all other cases the h4 would be different size.

Could anyone help me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, set the default width in your CSS.

```
.widgetContent h4 {
    width: 195px;
}
```

Then:

```
$('.widgetContent')       // all widgets
  .has('.thumbNail')      // but only those with a thumbnail
  .find('h4')             // find the <h4> children of those
  .css('width', '100px'); // and set the style
```

Comment: For a novice like me the above makes a lot of sense! Nice solution.

Comment: @Vikita now improved with `.has()` instead of `.filter(':has(...)')`

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
$(".widgetContent").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.thumbNail').length) {
        $(this).find('h4').css('width', '100px');
   } else {
        $(this).find('h4').css('width', '195px');
    }
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/9jdnY/1/

Comment: now it works, it just didn't save it the other time: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/9jdnY/1/

Comment: @Nicola FWIW, there's a lot of repetition in that code.  See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/dShZc/

Comment: Even better:) Thank you both very much!

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question correctly, you could do this...

```
$('.thumbNail + h4').css('fontSize','100px');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/5Sf2B/

This basically chooses any `h4` next to an element with class `.thumbNail`.

Here is a more readable example (at 25px): http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/5Sf2B/1/

The "all other cases" should be dealt with in the stylesheet.

Not sure why you want it that big, but there you go ;-)

**EDIT**

I may have interpreted the Q incorrectly, although the concept is the same.  If you want to change the `width` of the `h4` instead of the `font-size`, then just do this:

```
$('.thumbNail + h4').css('width','100px');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/5Sf2B/2/

Comment: Try `width` instead of `font-size`.

Comment: what if the h4 isn't immediately after the thumbnail?

Comment: @Ben did the OP want `width`?  I thought he wanted `font-size`. ;-)

Comment: @Jason G. Yup, he wanted width.

Comment: @Alnitak. True.  But the OP never said that and the code doesn't suggest it.

Comment: @Jason it's best never to assume anything about the DOM hierarchy unless the OP explicitly indicates that it's fixed.